# How to reverse bit of a number (k bits) using bitwise?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C reverse bits in unsigned integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144800/c-reverse-bits-in-unsigned-integer)
>   [How does this code work to reverse bits in number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184089/how-does-this-code-work-to-reverse-bits-in-number)

Given a number `n` with `k` bits, `(n < 2^k)`, is there a fast way to do it using bitwise? This is my `slow` solution:

```
int reverse_bit(int n, int bit_size) {
    bit_size--;

    int result = 0;
    while (n) {
        if ((n & 1) == 1)
            result += 1 * (1 << bit_size);

        n >>= 1;
        bit_size--;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This should have the solution: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ReverseParallel

Comment: Asked before: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144800/c-reverse-bits-in-unsigned-integer), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515715/bit-reversal-using-bitwise), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184089/how-does-this-code-work-to-reverse-bits-in-number).

Comment: Above mentioned duplicates describe it by using C. Here some code which written in more C++ way.

`template <typename T>
T reverse(T n, size_t nBits = sizeof(T) * 8)
{
    T reverse = 0;
    auto mask = 1;

    for (auto i = 0; i < nBits; ++i)
    {
        if (n & mask)
        {
            reverse |= (1 << (nBits - i - 1));
        }
        mask <<= 1;
    }

    return reverse;
}`